# button переключатель bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, html5, bootstrap

Здравствутуйте.

Хочется реализовать "переключатель" button как здесь forts.pro (покупка\продажа)

чтобы button переключал display и при этом менял сам свой цвет на активный.

Пример переключателя

```
function change(combo){
if(combo.value == '1'){
 document.getElementById('1').style.display = 'block';
}else{
document.getElementById('1').style.display = 'none';
}
}
```

кнопок будет таких 4 шт., соотсветсвенно и display